# How do I know if my Windows 7 Professional product key is original?

Tags: windows-7, validation

Our company Wants to buy 30 Windows 7 Professional OEM licenses. Somebody gave us some packages like this:

[image]

1. How can I be sure if this Windows 7 Professional package is original?
2. How many users can use this Windows? He gave us for 30 clients but what happens if we install this package for more than that? How can I find the number of users that can be installed with this?
3. How can I check the product key before installing Windows?

Comment: It says right at the top if the picture **Intended for system builders ONLY**. It's not legal for someone to sell it to you unless you're a system builder.

Comment: Before anyone points out things have changed since Jan 4, '11...I know that. But anyway.......

Answer (score 2):

That looks like a standard OEM pack.  If you crack that cardboard sleeve, what you should see [are the things detailed here by Microsoft as making it legit](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/genuine/what-to-look-for).

Comment: so how can I find the number of user? Can I install on more than 30 pc?

Comment: Oh, this is a SINGLE pack?  I was under the impression you meant you had 30 of these.  I'm not sure what the high-volume OEM packs look like but the point still stands - they should have holographic disks and COAs.  (See also @thepurplepixel's answer).

Comment: And you can only install as many copies as you have product keys.  How would you propose to do otherwise?

Comment: yes. I think so, so I should ask him to give us 30 other product key

Comment: I looked at that picture again and that's clearly a standard OEM single-license pack, as evidenced by the writing on the label I didn't bother to look at before.  You need one of these for each machine.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft's [How To Tell](http://www.microsoft.com/howtotell/) site provides a bunch of useful information about verifying the authenticity of media. Unfortunately, there is no way to pre-verify the authenticity of the product keys, as by doing so, you are forced to open the package to find the product keys.

As I recall, these System Builder Packs contain bundles of CDs/DVDs in sleeves with individual product keys on the back, but no certificate of authenticity. That may be a bit of a pain if every disc has a different product key, but if that's what you purchased, I guess you have to work with it.

Comment: Yes, We are going to buy just this package and the give the man 30x150$ for 30 computer, he didnt sell us 30 pack he gave us one pack for 30 user!! how can I to be sure that?

Comment: @user29373 The one package he gave you, if it is identical to the one in the picture you provided, likely contains either 30 separate media (CDs/DVDs), or a fewer number of media with a list of product keys. If he is selling you 30 licenses as part of a volume licenses, this is fraudulent and illegal, and Microsoft may revoke those licenses (if it is a System Builder pack, though, I doubt it).

Comment: Yes, He gave us that exactly pack, I open it, it contains one DVD that is holograms and has one COA with one product key on it. he said you can use this for 30 computer!!!

Comment: @user29373 Then you can probably use it on 30 computers. If it **doesn't** work, that's when I'd contact Microsoft and/or the seller.

Answer (score 1):

If you are buying an OEM license you will need a different key for each PC.
If he is selling a 30pack (which I doubt, as I think the most you can get is a 5pack) it would have to contain 30 stickers. One sticker per PC and each one would need to be activated separately.

To legally apply the licenses you should have built the PCs yourself and be selling them on to someone else, you are not allowed to buy them and stick them on some old XP machines, for example.

He may be selling you Client Access Licences (aka CALs) which allow a PC to access resources on a Windows Server.

Comment: maybe, but as you can see in image, it has written OEM version, no we don`t want to sell to anybody else, our company bought 30 Dell notebook and wants to buy original Windows 7 pro for them, and use them on our Network environment.

Comment: The package also says that it is 1 unit only which means 1 licence for 1 PC only.

Comment: Did you get the notebooks direct from Dell? They would be able to sell you genuine licenses.

Comment: @user29373 - you can't use OEM licenses for machines built by somebody else.  That's in violation of the terms and conditions.  You need to buy full retail versions or talk to Dell.